# Alterar a Status Bar para transparente em um Fragment dentro de uma Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-activity

Tenho uma `Activity` a qual possui um tema para sua Status Bar, porém a mesma tem influência em um `Fragment` ao qual quero outra cor na Status Bar.

Existe alguma maneira de eu alterar a cor da Status Bar apenas quando aquele `Fragment` for aberto, e voltar ao normal quando for fechado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alterar através do método `setStatusBarColor()`:

```
context.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Lembre-se que esta função está disponível apenas a partir da API 21 (`Lollipop`), então faça uma verificação antes de utiliza-la:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    context.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Com *Status Bar*, você se refere a **Actionbar/Toolbar**? Se sim, você pode mudar manualmente (código) com:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#CCFF0000")));
```

Dessa forma, quando o Fragment for criado você pode pegar a Activity, da Activity pegar o Fragment e mudar por código a cor da Actionbar.

**EDIT:**

Eu havia interpretado sua pergunta equivocadamente. A resposta do **sicachester** está correta.